# Inward offsetting a polygon recursively not requiring shape to be rigidly maintained

Tags: algorithm, matlab, computational-geometry, polygons

I start with a polygon, the blue contour. And then want to keep shrinking it inwards for say 4 depths. So in next  iteration, i will get something like the green contour. Notice the shape of the polygon is maintained at least that is what i want to signify. This step can be easily done using Polygon Clipping and Offsetting Matlab wrapper by Emmett for the c++  Clipper Library by Angus.

However, in next step i want to shrink the green polygon further. However, the green polygon cannot be shrunk further while maintaining the shape of the green contour. So an algorithm should adaptively shrink to the magenta contour. That is what i have in mind. The motivation comes from drawing contours in maps. As long as the contour generated by the adaptive process looks realistic enough, i am not particular about what shape modification is done to get to the magenta contour.

[image]

I am working in Matlab and have looked for available stuff in this direction rather than coding something from scratch. Most inward offsetting tools for polygons maintain the shape while shrinking like this:

[image]

Suggestions to shrink a polygon to one single smaller polygon would be helpful. Shape modification is allowed.

The code used to create above image is:

```
p=[110 80;65 391;438 425;120 329];
ngon.x=p(:,1);
ngon.y=p(:,2);

scale=2^15;
ngon.x=int64(ngon.x*scale);
ngon.y=int64(ngon.y*scale);
outtie=clipper(ngon,ngon,1);% perform redundant self-intersection (required)

outtie.x=int64(outtie.x);
outtie.y=int64(outtie.y);
offset=clipper(outtie,-10*scale,1);
innie.x=offset.x/scale;
innie.y=offset.y/scale;
innie.x=[innie.x;innie.x(1)];
innie.y=[innie.y;innie.y(1)];

figure;
hold on
fill(ngon.x,ngon.y,'y')
plot(innie.x,innie.y,'r','linewidth',2)
```

To mex the clipper fucntion, please see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36241-polygon-clipping-and-offsetting).

Comment: This is harder than it may seem. You need to define success carefully at the start. E.g. consider a barbell-shaped polygon. Shrinking it should produce two disconnected loops. Or should it? One fairly robust way to shrink by amount h is replace each segment in the original contour with a box where the segment forms one edge, the parallel edge is offset by h "inward", and the ends form a mitered joint. Then use a polygon differencing algorithm to subtract these polygons from the original contour.